# Show that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=x+1$ if $x>0$ is not open, nor closed, nor continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm trying to prove this:

> Show that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=x+1$ if $x>0$ is not open, nor closed, nor continuous.

My try:

> **Not open**
> : We take the open interval in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (-2,-1). Then, $f((-2,-1))=\{0\}$, that is closed, so $f$ is not open.
>
> **Not closed**: We take the closed interval in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ [-2,2]. Then, $f([-2,2])=\{0\}\cup(1,3]$, that is not closed, so $f$ is not closed.
>
> **Not continuous**: I've been trying but I'm not able to find an open interval on the image of $f$, that maps using $\ f^{-1}$ to a not open interval.

Can somebody light me up with this? I'd appreciate so much.Is my try correct at least until I got stuck?

EDIT: I only have the definition that $f$ is continuous if and only if every open interval in the sense of a topology of $\mathbb{R}$ goes, by $f^{-1}$, to an open interval.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hint: A function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous in the sense of topology if and only if it is continuous in the sense of calculus. If you graph $f$, at what point is it not continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw a picture you'll easily see that the only point of discontinuity is $x=0$. So you need to try there.

Look at, e.g. $(-1, 3)$

The first two items are fine.

Comment: But $-1$ is not defined on the image of $f$. I need to find an open interval on the image that takes me to a non open interval.

Comment: @Relure No, you need to find an open interval in the target space. $f^{-1} $ is not a function in this context. And $f^{-1} (\{-1\})$ is just the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show that a function $g:A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, is continuous at $x_0$ if, and only if, $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = g(x_0)$. Considering the above $f$, we have $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 1 \neq 0 = f(0)$. Therefore, $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: We're on a topological space (at least, I'm looking $\mathbb{R}$ as a topological space), the notion of limit is reserved for a metric spaces.

Comment: Not really. Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and $f: X \to Y$. Given $x_0 \in X$, we say $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L$ iff $\forall$ neighborhood $N_Y$ of $L$ there exists a neighborhood $N_X$ of $x_0$ such that if $x \in N_X$ then $f(x) \in N_Y$.

Comment: But it doesn't really matter, if you are looking at $\mathbb{R}$ with it's usual topology, then the topology is induced my the Euclidean metric and therefore all the theorems of calculus apply.